# Click event in Kendo ListView template

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik

How to configure click event using List View component? Debugging script not stopping on breakpoint inside addToCart()

Definition of ListView:

```js
$("#main").kendoListView({
    dataSource: items,
    template: kendo.template($("#item").html()),
    addToCart: function(e) {
        cart.add(e.data);
    }
});
```

Template:

```html
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="item">
    <li class="products">
        <strong>#: ProductName #</strong>
        <button class="add-to-cart" data-bind="click: addToCart">Add to cart</button>
    </li>
</script>
```

---

edit: it works if listView is constructed inline as a `kendo.observable`:

```js
var indexModel = kendo.observable({
    items: items,
    cart: cart,
    addToCart: function(e) {
        cart.add(e.data);
    }
});

kendo.bind($("#content"), indexModel);
```

```html
<section id="content">
    <ul data-role="listview" data-bind="source: items" data-template="item" id="main"></ul>
</section>

<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="item">
    <li class="products">
        <button class="add-to-cart" data-bind="click: addToCart">Add to cart</button>
    </li>
</script>
```

Comment: *"it works if listView is constructed inline"* so did you fixed it?

Comment: I fixed my problem but I would like to know, for future work, how to solve this by defining ListView in 1st way.

Comment: I would upvote your answer if you posed it as an answer. I suspect the reason is because ListView is not an observable. The declarative data binding in your working code applies to an observable. When you originally tried to add the click event there was no backing model to bind to. Not a perfect explanation but perhaps it helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, if you don't use a kendo observable, it's not a proper binding. For example, you can't use `<strong data-bind="text: ProductName"></strong>"` in your template, and you also can't bind an event to your button.

To make it work, you can add a jQuery event handler to your buttons, and retrieves the data item from the list view (note that `addToCart` is no longer defined inside the list view configuration):

```cs
function addToCart(e) {
    var li = $(e.currentTarget).parent(), 
        listView = $("#main").data().kendoListView, 
        dataItem = listView.dataItem(li);

    console.log(dataItem);
}

$('#main').on('click', '.add-to-cart', addToCart);
```

I've created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Metoule/ota9qgzo/2/) to demonstrate.

Comment: It's worth noting that a `ListView` edit template is a proper binding.